# Cannot run puppet agent on vanilla Foreman install

Tags: foreman

I've just installed Foreman 1.5 onto a CentOS 6.4 VM for evaluation. Following the installation instructions on the Foreman website, I got everything installed and working, up until I tried to run `puppet agent -t`. This gives me the error:

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find node 'foreman.mydomain.com'; cannot compile

I haven't been able to find anything helpful in the logs and I'm not sure how to start debugging this myself. The Foreman GUI is working fine and does have my host listed. Normally I'd check the site.pp manifest but obviously Foreman abstracts all that stuff. I'm not sure what else I can check?

Any help would be great!

Cheers,

Pete.

Comment: Is the Puppet Master Reachable From the Agents? http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/trouble_comms.html

Comment: I did go through that page - I can telnet, and I thought that Foreman replaced the standard Puppet console? If so, then yes I can access it.